# How to fix a crash issue invoked from Cairo library?

Tags: c++, crash, cairo

I have a legacy application that uses the Cairo library to draw images and texts. Sometimes this application crashes. I don't know the reproduction path, it's pretty rare and random. I have created crash dumps and found that every time I got an access violation from `cairo_win32_surface_get_dc` [function](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Win32-Surfaces.html#cairo-win32-surface-get-dc).

Here is the source code from Cairo -

```cpp
HDC  cairo_win32_surface_get_dc (cairo_surface_t *surface)
{
    if (surface->backend->type == CAIRO_SURFACE_TYPE_WIN32)
    return to_win32_surface(surface)->dc;

    if (_cairo_surface_is_paginated (surface)) {
    cairo_surface_t *target = _cairo_paginated_surface_get_target (surface);
    if (target->backend->type == CAIRO_SURFACE_TYPE_WIN32_PRINTING)
        return to_win32_surface(target)->dc;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

This function returns the HDC associated with this surface, or NULL if none. It also returns NULL if the surface is not a win32 surface.

From the crash dump I've found, `surface->backend` was NULL when this crash occurred. Which is expected if you look at the code above, it doesn't check if `surface` or `surface->backend` is NULL or not.

My application's code looks like below -

```
if( mySurface ) {
    hDC = cairo_win32_surface_get_dc(mySurface);
}
```

My idea was to add an extra check if `mySurface->backend` is NULL or not before calling `cairo_win32_surface_get_dc` but, `mySurface->backend` is not accessible from here. Gives me the following error -

```
Error           C2027   use of undefined type '_cairo_surface'
Error (active)  E0393   pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
```

Also note that this block doesn't crash always, so I'm unable to figure out what's going wrong here.

After googling a bit, I found some people are checking for any previous error like this-

```
if (cairo_surface_status(mySurface) == 0) {
    hDC = cairo_win32_surface_get_dc(mySurface);
}
```

Will this change fix my issue? Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In terms of coding practises, I would recommend defensive programming for catching these sort of null pointer problem, by define pre/post conditions on the functions that mutate those variables.  Also, I don't understand why `mySurface->backend` is not accessible before the function call?

Comment: @Mansoor, I have added the error log when I try to access `mySurface->backend`